# oracle unique index on table with respect to an owner

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am not a DBA and hence, asking this question. Can someone please tell me what is the significance of below mentioned query :

```
select i.index_name, 
        NVL(c.column_name,' '), 
        NVL(c.DESCEND, 'ASC') 
    from all_indexes i, all_ind_columns c 
    where i.index_name = c.index_name 
    and (i.INDEX_TYPE = 'NORMAL' or i.INDEX_TYPE = 'FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL') 
    and i.table_name = name 
    and i.owner = c.index_owner 
    and i.table_owner = owner
    and c.table_name = name
    and c.table_owner = owner
    and i.uniqueness =  'UNIQUE' 
    order by c.index_name, c.column_position
```

Is it kind of a constraint check with respect to indexes. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "constraint check with respect to indexes"? I am not familiar with the concept. In any case: this query takes as inputs an owner (schema, user) of the database and the name of a table in that schema (owned by that owner). It finds all the unique indexes (indexes that enforce unique values) on that table, including for example the index for the primary key, and which column or set of columns the index is on, and whether the index is sorted ascending or descending. It's a relatively standard query to find out information about unique indexes on a table in a schema.

For example, most Oracle installations come with the standard sample schema (owner) HR, which has several tables including one named EMPLOYEES. This table has a primary key, the employee id, and an additional unique key on employee emails. Here is the query, with the `owner` and `name` hard-coded to `'HR'` and `'EMPLOYEES'` respectively, and the output. Note that whoever wrote the query didn't give aliases to the last two columns in `SELECT`, so the output looks a bit ugly for that reason.

```
select i.index_name, 
        NVL(c.column_name,' '), 
        NVL(c.DESCEND, 'ASC') 
    from all_indexes i, all_ind_columns c 
    where i.index_name = c.index_name 
    and (i.INDEX_TYPE = 'NORMAL' or i.INDEX_TYPE = 'FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL') 
    and i.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' 
    and i.owner = c.index_owner 
    and i.table_owner = 'HR'
    and c.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'
    and c.table_owner = 'HR'
    and i.uniqueness =  'UNIQUE' 
    order by c.index_name, c.column_position
;

INDEX_NAME     NVL(C.COLUMN_NAME,'')  NVL(C.DESCEND,'ASC')
-------------  ---------------------  --------------------
EMP_EMAIL_UK   EMAIL                  ASC
EMP_EMP_ID_PK  EMPLOYEE_ID            ASC
```